# Mandrill giving invalid app key error

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, mailchimp

I am just trying to integrate mandrill mail sending with my app below is my code in php

```
$args = array(
    'key' => '73357ad2-e59e-4669---------',
    'message' => array(
        "html" => "<p>\r\n\tHi Adam,</p>\r\n<p>\r\n\tThanks for <a href=\"http://mandrill.com\">registering</a>.</p>\r\n<p>etc etc</p>",
        "text" => null,
        "from_email" => "xxx@xxx.com",
        "from_name" => "SIVOnline",
        "subject" => "Your recent registration",
        "to" => array(array("email" => "xxx@xxx.com")),
        "track_opens" => true,
        "track_clicks" => true,
        "auto_text" => true
    )   
);
// Open a curl session for making the call

$curl = curl_init('https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json' );
// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
// Set the POST arguments to pass on
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($args));

// Make the REST call, returning the result
$response = curl_exec($curl);


 // Close the connection
    curl_close( $curl );
```

and it is giving me invalid api key after regenarating the key still i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't JSON-encode the `$args` variable when passing it to the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS setopt call.

BTW, you should try to make a users/ping call first.

Comment: what does making the users/ping call first do?

Comment: @Williams Castillo - like 916 Networks, what is the purpose of checking the users/ping call first?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Mandrill official API Located here https://packagist.org/packages/mandrill/mandrill?

You would do it like this

```
require_once(Mandrill.php);

$apikey = "YOUR-API-KEY";

$Mandrill = new Mandrill($apikey);


$params = array(
        "html" => "<p>\r\n\tHi Adam,</p>\r\n<p>\r\n\tThanks for <a href=\"http://mandrill.com\">registering</a>.</p>\r\n<p>etc etc</p>",
        "text" => null,
        "from_email" => "xxx@xxx.com",
        "from_name" => "chris french",
        "subject" => "Your recent registration",
        "to" => array(array("email" => "xxx@xxxx.com")),
        "track_opens" => true,
        "track_clicks" => true,
        "auto_text" => true
);

$Mandrill->messages->send($params, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can get a fully featured Mandrill API wrapper class for PHP

... it's contained in a WordPress plug-in package: [wpMandrill](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpmandrill/)